# UWP add drag and drop action to Grid more than one cell

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I want to build an app with UWP(Universal windows platform).
with an app, I wanted to implement a "drag-and-drop" functionality.
I used some properties called "AllowDrop and "DragOver".
but I got a problem with grid or some xaml hiearchy structure.

When I Drag and Drop any File to an App, any position of it, I want an App to accept it.
but with an unknown problem, the App accept file with only specific area of it.
I hope Following image will help you understand what problems I am suffered by.
[my Intent(left) but It works(right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBNxF.png)

below is source code (one is xaml source, after one is csharp).

```
<Page 
    x:Class="eeee_textRandomizeUWP.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:eeee_textRandomizeUWP"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid AllowDrop="True" DragOver="Grid_DragOver">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>

            <TextBlock Text="파일을 올려주세요" FontSize="{ThemeResource ListViewHeaderItemThemeFontSize}" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0"/>
            <ListView Name="MainFileList">
                <ListViewItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <TextBlock Text="&#xE8E5;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" /> 
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
            </ListView>

        </StackPanel> 
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

Following source is csharp

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// 빈 페이지 항목 템플릿에 대한 설명은 https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x412에 나와 있습니다.

namespace eeee_textRandomizeUWP
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 자체적으로 사용하거나 프레임 내에서 탐색할 수 있는 빈 페이지입니다.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainFileList_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Grid_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.AcceptedOperation = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataPackageOperation.Copy;

            e.DragUIOverride.Caption = "드래그 앤 드롭을 하여 파일을 등록해주세요";
            e.DragUIOverride.IsCaptionVisible = true;
            e.DragUIOverride.IsContentVisible = true;
            e.DragUIOverride.IsGlyphVisible = true;

        }
    }
}
```

I think that I have no problem with Csharp part, but with xaml part.
I wonder that It just work with just one grid cell even I add drag action to
"Main Grid" literally.
I said drag-and-drop works just one cell of grid. but when I consider cell's height, the valid area is too small.

when I find this problem, I moved my action to "Page" tag. but It worked same as the action was in "Grid" tag. I don't know What is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It hasn't worked in the Grid tag since you have another box overlaying it, so you dragging anything above the other layer, not the grid itself.

Comment: I don't think so. with your advice - no above other layer ( Grid.Row=0, .Col=1, Grid.Row=1, Col=1, Grid.Row=1, Col=0) should work properly . but it doesn't.
with some test, I think it is related to "Grid". With just one grid

Comment: Check the textblock - when its height and width is not being set, he would chose by default the size of the grid, and you would drag into it.

Comment: I appreciate your kindness. but I still Wonder the missing part that i don't understand. can you check below xaml source with my original csharp source?. why It doens't work?

    <Grid
            Height="1000"
            Width="1000"
            AllowDrop="True" 
            DragOver="Grid_DragOver" 
            Drop="Grid_Drop"
         >
    </Grid>

Just one Grid Xaml.

Comment: actually I set a grid size with asterik. even I set a Grid's Height Width with Constant Value - It doesn't work..

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry - my mistake - You can't drop anything inside a grid; but you need to create a canvas or an GridView to drop whatever you want there, but the Grid itself should include `AllowDrop = "true"`, read more about it in here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/edda1e47-217e-4bac-8b2f-581552b45e43/uwpxamldrag-and-drop-issue-onto-a-grid?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Thank you man, I solve Problem with your advice.
but still have wonder why i should do like this. I ended up with adding following canvas In end of grid.         <Canvas 
        Background="Transparent"
            Grid.RowSpan="2" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
            AllowDrop="True" 
            DragOver="Grid_DragOver" 
            Drop="Grid_Drop" >
        </Canvas>
... but i wonder without setting canvas's background - it doesn't work. .... -_-..I got confused. but technically It works, so fine. thanks! ^_^

Comment: Glad I helped you, take care

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this source. just adding canvas tag in end of grid tag. I still wonder why should i do like this. but It works. don't subtract Canvas's Background setting.

```
<Page 
    x:Class="eeee_textRandomizeUWP.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:eeee_textRandomizeUWP"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="파일을 올려주세요" FontSize="{ThemeResource ListViewHeaderItemThemeFontSize}" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0"/>
            <ListView Name="MainFileList">
                <ListViewItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <TextBlock Text="&#xE8E5;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" /> 
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <TextBlock Text="&#xE8E5;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" /> 
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <TextBlock Text="&#xE8E5;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" /> 
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
            </ListView>

        </StackPanel>

        <ListView Grid.Column="1">
            <ListViewItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <TextBlock Text="&#xE8E5;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" /> 
                    </StackPanel>
            </ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <TextBlock Text="&#xE8E5;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" /> 
                    </StackPanel>
            </ListViewItem>

            <ListViewItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <TextBlock Text="&#xE8E5;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" /> 
                    </StackPanel>
            </ListViewItem>
        </ListView>

        <Canvas 
            Background="Transparent"
            Grid.RowSpan="2" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
            AllowDrop="True" 
            DragOver="Grid_DragOver" 
            >
        </Canvas>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```